# Does AWS S3 offer any kind of rate limiting or protection against abuse for publicly accessible files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rate-limiting

I have a web app which serves media files (in other words pretty large) with public access.  The files are hosted on S3.  I'm wondering if AWS offers any kind of abuse-protection, for example detection or prevention against download hogs via some type of rate limiting.  A scenario might be a single source re-downloading the same content repeatedly.  I was hoping there might be some mechanism to detect that behavior and either take preventative action or notify me.

I'm looking at AWS docs and don't see anything but perhaps I'm not looking smartly enough.

How do folks who host files which are available publicly handle this?

Answer (score 2):

S3 is mostly a file storage service, with elementary web server capabilities. I would highly recommend you place a CDN between your end users and S3. A good CDN will provide protection from the sort of abuse you are talking about, while also serving the files to the user more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mostly worried about how the abuse will affect your bills (and they can get very large so its good to be concerned about this), I would suggest that you put in some billing alerts on your account that alarm when certain thresholds are reached.

I have a step alarms set on my account so that I know when it hits 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% of what I budget each month. That way, for example, if I hit an alarm that tells me I have used 25% of my budget in the first two days of the month, I know I better look into it.